# Rails Association Has_Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to fetch the information from books associated with a customer but seem that the middle association doesn't works

Here my model

```
Book
    has_one :book_manager
    has_one :customer, :through => :book_manager

Customer
    has_many :book_managers
    has_many :books, :through => :book_managers

Book_Manager
    belongs_to :customer
    belongs_to :book
```

The field are has follow

```
Book          Customer      book_manager
id            id            id
description   email         customer_id
              password      book_id
              first         visible
              last
```

When fetching the information in my def edit, the following is successfull

```
@book = Book.first
@book = Book.last
```

The following seem to fails

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@book = @customer.books.first
@book = @customer.books.order("created_at DESC").first
```

Is there something i miss?

I also try to verify by creating an index for book_manager controller and view and nothing appears, its seems its empty. The way i created the books was as follow

BookController

```
def create
@book = current_customer.books.build(params[:book])
    if @book.save
        flash[:success] = "Book Created"
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        render 'customer/edit'
    end
end
```

I have updated my relationship but still doesn't to work

The idea is has follow

A customer update his status, which consist of many subsection such has

```
-Phone
-Book
-Interest
```

Under book I should see if there exist an empty book related to the customer, if so then showcase the last book. if not then customer see blank and can create a new one

The books managers is only there to maintain the relationship and also because i want to keep the data and i want to allow user to determine if we show this data to everyone else in the site or not.

Comment: `@book = current_customer.books.build(params[:book])` I think it's incorrect. The customer has_many book_managers, therefore, Rails doesn't know which one you want to use when building the new book. Explicitly assigning it to a particular `book_manager` may help

Comment: Oh.. wait a book is only associated to one book manager, i might need to change my relationship

Comment: Start your thought process from the viewpoint of the customer UI. They will probably visit the book manager page and see multiple managers. When they open a manager they'll see multiple books. It seems most natural to me for a customer to "own" book managers, each of which will "own" books. The "owning" in your case will translate into `has_many` on the "owner" side and `belongs_to` on the "ownee" side.

Comment: Another way to decide on which class is an "owner" of a collection of another class, is that it makes sense for the owner class to exist without the ownee, while it doesn't make sense for the ownee to exist without an owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. I'm doing this in sqlite3 (with in-memory database) just for demonstration purposes.

Connect (in rails, use the database.yml instead):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :adapter => 'sqlite3', :database => ':memory:'
```

Setup classes:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_managers
  has_many :books, :through => :book_managers
end

class BookManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book_manager
  def customer
    book_manager.customer
  end
end
```

Create schema (This is here just to show the columns. In rails, use migrations):

```
Book.connection.create_table(Book.table_name) do |t|
  t.string :description
  t.integer :book_manager_id
end
BookManager.connection.create_table(BookManager.table_name) do |t|
   t.boolean :visible
  t.integer :customer_id
end
Customer.connection.create_table(Customer.table_name) do |t|
  t.string :email
  t.string :password
  t.string :first
  t.string :last
end
```

Create a record

```
cust = Customer.new :email => 'user@example.com'
cust.book_managers.build :visible => true
cust.book_managers.first.books.build :description => 'the odyssey'
cust.save!
```

Retrieve

```
cust = Customer.find 1
# test the has_many :through
cust.books
# test the Book#customer method
Book.first.customer
```

Comment: I am not to sure by what you mean by : def customer book_manager.customers end

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by def customer in the book model??. What does this do? I have never seen this in rails tutorial

Comment: @Jseb I'm defining a Book instance method called `customer`. When you have a book object, you can call `book.customer` to get the customer object that owns the book. I strongly suggest going through a ruby tutorial, otherwise you won't get very far with rails. [Here's one](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=09) that explains instance methods in classes.

Comment: @Jseb Try running my code in an irb session. Run `irb -r active_record` and paste in my code. Pay special attention to how the Retrieve section works. As you try things out, things will gradually start to make more sense.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know you could define a method that would associate thing together, didn't know rails was that close to ruby

Comment: @Jseb you definitely can. It's all ruby code. Now that you understand that, please try to understand why I declare the associations in the way I did.

Comment: Well i think your association make more sense, then mine customer one-to-many book_manager and book_manager one-to-many books and you can retrieve book.customer the owner that make sense, in your building you are then setting up first an instance of a book manager then build a book with the new information. Just a bit confused someone told me in other place to forget about bookmanager and just do the way i did previously, what would be the main difference??

Comment: My main issue remain how would i convert it to edit if it doesn't exist? in a controller, the retrieve and create

Comment: @Jseb If a customer only needs one book_manager, I agree that you should remove it, and use `Customer.has_many :books`. In terms of creating and editing a customer via a form, I suggest reading up on `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `attr_accessible`. Here's [one blog](http://buzzcodington.wordpress.com/2011/12/09/my-idiotic-encounter-with-accepts_nested_attributes_for-in-rails-3/) that should help. If you need more help with that, please search stackoverflow or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks appreciated, my relation are working now, just my create and edit don't work